# SAML 2.0 service provider implementation

Tags: saml, service-provider

I am implementing SAML2.0 ServiceProvider in java using spring-security-saml-sample code. After successful login response gets redirect to root path(welcome file) of application.How to redirect it to any controller ?

Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: I have tried with adding                                    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/myControllerURL"/>
</bean>                                                                             But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize URL to which user gets redirected after successful authentication by changing bean `successRedirectHandler`, for example to:

```
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/myControllerURL"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I had added the above bean in securitycontext.xml file but it doesn't work.After adding this code, it redirects to welcome file mentioned in web.xml

Comment: Then enable logging on debug level and add logs from the whole SSO process to the question.

Comment: I am getting following logs:-                                     SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing
- AuthNResponse;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;http://localhost:8080/ServiceProvider/saml/metadata;http://idp.ssocircle.com;tejas.chougule@xxxxx.in;;
authentication org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@4a5c013f: Principal: tejas.chougule@xxxx.in; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities

Comment: What I was asking about are complete logs with debug level enabled, this is just a very small part of the information which could help to troubleshoot your problem. One thing you could try is replacing class SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler with SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the general way to maintain state through the login process, SAML2 is expected to preserve the `RelayState` variable (pass it alongside the `SAMLRequest`). Put whatever you'd like in it. I like base64'd json.